# To check if string contains particular word

Tags: java, android

So how do you check if a string has a particular word in it?

So this is my code:

```
a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(d.contains("Hey")){
                c.setText("OUTPUT: SUCCESS!"); 
            }else{
                c.setText("OUTPUT: FAIL!");  
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm getting an error.

Comment: Read about regular expressions (RegEx) for more info.

Comment: The checking part seems fine. What's the error?

Comment: What's the error? What is `d`? What is `c`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Not as complicated as they say, check this you will not regret.**

```
String sentence = "Check this answer and you can find the keyword with this code";
String search  = "keyword";

if ( sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {

   System.out.println("I found the keyword");

} else {

   System.out.println("not found");

}
```

You can change the `toLowerCase()` if you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer fthopkins. Its an old question, but i faced a similar situation today at work. The above code searches for charsequence not the word. For example:-
 If we want to catch only "keyword" and not any extensions like "keyword_1", the above code will not work. One way to avoid this can be to search with String contains function for " keyword " (note the two blank spaces on either side ) - is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: @JavaTec you'll need to use a regex to search for words properly. Similar to m0skit0's answer (and see that answer for using compiled expressions if you use the same expression over and over), you'll want to do this: `if (d.matches("\\bkeyword\\b")) {/*success*/}`. `\b` (`\\b` in a string to escape the backslash) matches a "word boundary", i.e. the edges of a word. The advantage over using blank spaces is it will properly match things like "sentence with a keyword." (full stop instead of space) or even "keyword" (no space at beginning or end).

Comment: Thanks @LoganPickup - i did end up using `\\b` (back then in October) and it worked fine.

Comment: This code only checks if a string contains another string. The semantics don't hold for actual words. _cheese_ != _cheeseburger_ and _cat_ != _catalogue_.

Answer (score 12):

`.contains()` is perfectly valid and a good way to check.

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Since you didn't post the error, I guess `d` is either null or you are getting the "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method" error.

To make sure it's not null, first check for null in the if statement. If it's the other error, make sure `d` is declared as `final` or is a member variable of your class. Ditto for `c`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use regular expressions:

```
if (d.matches(".*Hey.*")) {
    c.setText("OUTPUT: SUCCESS!");
} else {
    c.setText("OUTPUT: FAIL!");  
}
```

`.*` -> 0 or more of any characters

`Hey` -> The string you want

If you will be checking this often, it is better to compile the regular expression in a `Pattern` object and reuse the `Pattern` instance to do the checking.

```
private static final Pattern HEYPATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*Hey.*");
[...]
if (HEYPATTERN.matcher(d).matches()) {
    c.setText("OUTPUT: SUCCESS!");
} else {
    c.setText("OUTPUT: FAIL!");  
}
```

Just note this will also match `"Heyburg"` for example since you didn't specify you're searching for `"Hey"` as an independent word. *If you only want to match `Hey` as a word, you need to change the regex to* `.*\\bHey\\b.*`

Comment: Oh my bad. I forgot the d = b.getText().toString(); part.

Comment: I guess you intented to write this comment as a comment **on your question**.

Comment: @m0skit0 can we do this matching by ignoring the case, i.e. i want to match if a sentence contains android/Android it should return true.

Comment: @KaranKhurana Depends on what OP actually wants or means by "word".

Comment: @m0skit0 what is OP ?

Answer (score 5):

The other answer (to date) appear to check for substrings rather than words. Major difference.

With the help of [this article](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/regex/java-regex-specific-contain-word/), I have created this simple method:

```
static boolean containsWord(String mainString, String word) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + word + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); // "\\b" represents any word boundary.
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mainString);
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **contains**

```
String sentence = "Check this answer and you can find the keyword with this code";
String search = "keyword";

if (sentence.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {

  System.out.println("I found the keyword..!");

} else {

  System.out.println("not found..!");

}
```

Comment: Sorry. I have used contains instead of indexOf

Answer (score 2):

It's been correctly pointed out above that finding a given word in a sentence is not the same as finding the charsequence, and can be done as follows if you don't want to mess around with regular expressions.

```
boolean checkWordExistence(String word, String sentence) {
    if (sentence.contains(word)) {
        int start = sentence.indexOf(word);
        int end = start + word.length();

        boolean valid_left = ((start == 0) || (sentence.charAt(start - 1) == ' '));
        boolean valid_right = ((end == sentence.length()) || (sentence.charAt(end) == ' '));

        return valid_left && valid_right;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Output**:

```
checkWordExistence("the", "the earth is our planet"); true
checkWordExistence("ear", "the earth is our planet"); false
checkWordExistence("earth", "the earth is our planet"); true
```

**P.S**
Make sure you have filtered out any commas or full stops beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution-1:** - If you want to search for a combination of characters or an independent word from a sentence.

```
String sentence = "In the Name of Allah, the Most Beneficent, the Most Merciful."
if (sentence.matches(".*Beneficent.*")) {return true;}
else{return false;}
```

**Solution-2:** - There is another possibility you want to search for an independent word from a sentence then **Solution-1** will also return true if you searched a word exists in any other word. For example, If you will search **cent** from a sentence containing this word ** Beneficent** then **Solution-1** will return true. For this remember to add space in your regular expression.

```
String sentence = "In the Name of Allah, the Most Beneficent, the Most Merciful."
if (sentence.matches(".* cent .*")) {return true;}
else{return false;}
```

Now in **Solution-2** it wll return **false** because no independent **cent** word exist.

**Additional**: You can add or remove space on either side in 2nd solution according to your requirements.

Comment: Are you sure this would work? Look at how Beneficent has a comma after it instead of a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
   String sentence = "Check this answer and you can find the keyword with this code";
    String search = "keyword";
```

Compare the line of string  in given string

```
if ((sentence.toLowerCase().trim()).equals(search.toLowerCase().trim())) {
System.out.println("not found");
}
else {  
    System.out.println("I found the keyword"); 
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is mostly the same as your other answer here. Please don't repost; rather edit your older answer to become better. Why it's downvoted can be because it's incorrect (try changing the keyword e.g. to `asdf` and have the code report it found it).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (someString.indexOf("Hey")>=0) 
     doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post is old, but I came across it and used the "wrong" usage. The best way to find a keyword is using `.contains`, example:

```
if ( d.contains("hello")) {
            System.out.println("I found the keyword");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordContain {

    public static boolean wordCheck(String[] array, String word) {

        boolean check = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].equals(word)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return check;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Getting the value from the Scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = scan.nextLine();
        String word = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        // Split the sentence...
        String[] array = sentence.toLowerCase().split(" ");

        // pass the value to the wordCheck method
        boolean result = wordCheck(array, word);
        System.out.println(result);

        scan.close();
    }
}
```