# how to detect if word is on the sentence - android

Tags: android, arrays, search

i try to create a search word on array but i did not know how to detect if the word is on the sentence.
i use the code on this link.
[To check if string contains particular word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134773/to-check-if-string-contains-particular-word)

this is the code i'm using now. but it not work.

```
for(int x=0;x<=count;x++){
String sentence = name[x] ;
String search  = myEditText.getText().toString() ;
                        if (sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {
                         name[x] = name2;
                            schoolid[x] = id2;
}
}
```

Comment: "hello there, here is how you normally search".contains("hello there")

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM `contains(s)` <==> `indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;`. OP code should work anyway no ?

Comment: just to mention .. this is rather a Java question than it is "android"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like @MLProgrammer-CiM said:
Public methods of the [java.lang.String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) class:

```
boolean contains(CharSequence cs)
```

> Returns true if this string contains
>   the charss from the given CharSequence.

this means that the following will return true if search is contained in sentence

```
sentence.contains(search);
```