# How to check certain words on a string?

Tags: java, string, case-insensitive

```
    if (c.getQuery().contains("update") || c.getQuery().contains("delete") || c.getQuery().contains("truncate")
            || c.getQuery().contains("drop")) {
        throw new MensagemException(Mensagens.getMensagem("Only select is allowed"));
```

I have this simple code, that checks the string query. But it only checks lower case, what can I do to make it also verify any upper case without writing this over and over?

Comment: Use `compareToIgnoreCase`

Comment: @Dimitri that wouldn't work because the OP's intent is not to compare the whole string

Comment: This question duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134773/to-check-if-string-contains-particular-word 

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-a-case-insensitive-manner-in

Comment: Also just to note: if your query will be by any chance something like: `select date_updated from tableA` you will get a false positive...

Comment: Have you considered handling user grants in your DB instead of this?

Comment: @John C why you putting same question again and again, By changing It's contains logic differently? You must search for help before putting you question over stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Java strings don't have a `containsIgnoreCase` method, unfortunately. One way around this is to convert your input to lower case (or upper case, take your pick), and check it for the lower case words you're searching:

```
String toSearch = c.getQuery().toLowerCase();
if (toSearch.contains("update") || 
    toSearch.contains("delete") || 
    toSearch.contains("truncate") || 
    toSearch.contains("drop")) {
        throw new MensagemException
            (Mensagens.getMensagem("Only select is allowed"));
}
```

Comment: I believe this answer is just wrong. The question is surely an XY problem example; you don't check if a SQL query is a select by using a 'contains' on other SQL key words. This answer will break as soon as any field from the table contains one of those strings (e.g. select updated_on from mytable); at best you could use startsWith and assume only one query is being executed but trying to solve "how do I detect a non-select SQL query" is surely the actual question rather than what they have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a few enhancements:

```
final String cQuery = c.getQuery(); // retrieve only once
// check null, convert query to lower case so case won't matter anymore
final String cQueryLower = cQuery == null ? null : cQuery.toLowerCase();
if (cQueryLower.contains("update") || cQueryLower.contains("delete") || cQueryLower.contains("truncate") || cQueryLower.contains("drop")) {
    throw new MensagemException(Mensagens.getMensagem("Only select is allowed"));
}
```

You could try this too: `if (!cQueryLower.contains("select"))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `toLowerCase()` so you can check all variants of uppercase and lowercase with lowercase

```
if (c.getQuery().toLowerCase().contains("update") || c.getQuery().toLowerCase().contains("delete") || c.getQuery().toLowerCase().contains("truncate")
            || c.getQuery().toLowerCase().contains("drop")) {
        throw new MensagemException(Mensagens.getMensagem("Only select is allowed"));
```

I mean it must work like this. I have not tested it

Answer (score 0):

you can transform your string to lower case and then keep the same thing you are doing, should be like this :

```
String queryToLowerCase = c.getQuery().toLowerCase();
if (queryToLowerCase .contains("update") || queryToLowerCase .contains("delete") 
      || queryToLowerCase .contains("truncate") || queryToLowerCase .contains("drop")) {
    throw new MensagemException(Mensagens.getMensagem("Only select is allowed"));
```